# Combining django queryset objects having similar values

Tags: python, django

It's an eCom site that I am working on. I need to filter results based on email, as in obtain all those orders placed by this email account. On executing the query `OrderItem.objects.filter(order__email='john@john.com').select_related('order')` I get queryset object for each product. So if an order had multiple products then each product is a set on it's own. What I need is all items combined in the one set for an order ID so that I can iterate through them in the template.

`OrderItem.objects.filter(order__email='john@john.com').select_related('order').values('order_id').annotate(ct=Count('pk'))` - This query gets all those IDs and shows how many sets are there per ID. Likewise I just need the results but with other fields like created_date, order_id, transaction_id, product.

I have explored the django documentation but don't seem to find an appropriate solution. Another option is to manually loop through each item in the queryset and segregate based on the order_id having multiple items but then again that doesn't seem efficient. So any thoughts on how to proceed would be great.

Models are below:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return "Order #{},Date:{}".format(self.id,self.created_date)



class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(PRODUCT_VARIANT_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return "Quantity:{},Item:{},{}".format(self.quantity, self.product.get_product_title(),self.order)
```

Result of query 1:(There are 2 orders placed by this email ID) `OrderItem.objects.filter(order__email='john@john.com').select_related('order')`

```
<QuerySet [<OrderItem: Quantity:3,Item:sampleitem 1,Order #21,Date:2019-06-07 06:14:22.929052+00:00>, <OrderItem: Quantity:1,Item:sampleitem 91,Order #22,Date:2019-06-24 05:33:16.509479+00:00>, <OrderItem: Quantity:2,Item:sampleitem 44,Order
 #22,Date:2019-06-24 05:33:16.509479+00:00>, <OrderItem: Quantity:1,Item:sampleitem 8,Order #22,Date:2019-06-24 05:33:16.509479+00:00>]>
```

Result of query 2:
`OrderItem.objects.filter(order__email='john@john.com').select_related('order').values('order_id').annotate(ct=Count('pk'))`

```
<QuerySet [{'order_id': 21, 'ct': 1}, {'order_id': 22, 'ct': 3}]>
```

Comment: Update: I came across the {%regroup%} template tag which has led me to the result I want.